# getOwnerComponent() returns undefined in controller of which view was embedded on-demand

Tags: sapui5

I want to nest a second view into my root view if some requirements are met. This works fine by creating a XMLView object and adding it to the `<page>` aggregation of the `<App>` element. But when I try to access the default model (which is created by the `manifest.json` file) via `this.getOwnerComponent().getModel()`, it throws:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getModel' of undefined

It worked in the root controller but in the nested controller, `this.getOwnerComponent()` returned `undefined` again.

It even works if the view is added right at the beginning in the root view. Maybe I'm adding it the wrong way to the view in my controller?

---

***RootView.view.xml:***

```xml
<mvc:View controllerName="test.demo.controller.RootView" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
    <App id="app" xmlns="sap.m">
        <Page id="page" title="{i18n>title}">
            <Button text="load nested view" press=".onLoadButtonPress"/>
        </Page>
    </App>
</mvc:View>
```

***RootView.controller.js:***

```js
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/XMLView"
], function (Controller, XMLView) {
    "use strict";

    return Controller.extend("test.demo.controller.RootView", {
        onLoadButtonPress: function () {
            this.mDefault = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel(); // works just fine
            alert(this.mDefault);
            XMLView.create({
                viewName: "test.demo.view.NestedView"
            }).then(function(oView) {
                this.byId("page").addContent(oView);
            }.bind(this));
        }
    });
});
```

***NestedView.view.xml:***

```xml
<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" controllerName="test.demo.controller.NestedView">
  <!-- ... -->
</mvc:View>
```

***NestedView.controller.js:***

```js
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"
], function (Controller) {
    "use strict";

    return Controller.extend("test.demo.controller.NestedView", {
        onInit: function () {
            this.mDefault = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel(); // throws Uncaught TypeError: this.getOwnerComponent() is undefined
            alert(this.mDefault);
        }
    });
});
```

In the `manifest.json`, I added the `GWSAMPLE_BASIC` OData service as the default model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the caller in the application code creates on-demand a view or any other instance of ManagedObject, from which the owner component information needs to be accessible, it should be done within the method [**`runAsOwner`** from your target `sap.ui.core.Component`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.core.Component#methods/sap.ui.core.Component.getOwnerIdFor). For example:

```js
// XMLView required from "sap/ui/core/mvc/XMLView"
onLoadButtonPress: async function() {
  const fn = () => XMLView.create({ viewName: "test.demo.view.NestedView" });
  const oView = await this.getOwnerComponent().runAsOwner(fn);
  this.byId("page").addContent(oView);
},
```

**Sample:** [https://embed.plnkr.co/29UrnDHpTHquNWuH](https://embed.plnkr.co/29UrnDHpTHquNWuH?show=controller%2FApp.controller.js,controller%2FNested.controller.js,preview)

According to the API reference:

> Ownership for objects is only checked by the framework at the time when they are created. It is not checked or updated afterwards. And it can only be detected **while the `Component.runAsOwner` function is executing.** Without further action, this is only the case while the content of a UIComponent is constructed or when a Router creates a new View and its content. [(source)](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.core.Component#methods/sap.ui.core.Component.getOwnerComponentFor)

Then in the controller of the nested view, calling `this.getOwnerComponent()` returns the correctly assigned component instead of `undefined`, and thus `this.getOwnerComponent().getModel()` works.

---

**Tip:** when loading fragments, favor the [controller API `loadFragment`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller#methods/loadFragment) over `Fragment.load` since `loadFragment` automatically calls `Fragment.load` with the controller's component`.runAsOwner`.<sup>[src](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/a4f801d35e04671d15e78d3919720ddcdebcc97a/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller.js#L824-L826)</sup>